# Switch user to root and run execute the rest of the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I to change the user to root and run the rest of the commands as root in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if the current `uid` is zero, and if not, re-execute the script as root, e.g.,

```
[[ $UID = 0 ]] || exec sudo $0 "$@"
```

For instance, making that the second line of the script (after `"#!/bin/bash"`) would do what was asked.

If there is a lengthy part in the beginning where the original user was not needed, do that with an if-statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $UID = 0 ]]
then
    : do privileged stuff
else
    : do unprivileged stuff
    exec sudo $0 "$@"
fi
```

The `$UID` value is bash-specific (used because the question was tagged with `bash`).  More portable scripts would use the output of `id`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for prompt response,Acutally i need to stop my applicaiton services with my user and then i need to switch as root and execute the rest of the commands

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the setuid bit.